# Error Running Android Application With Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to integrate Parse library to my app.
I have done everything from the [quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/existing) provided by Parse.
My code compiles properly but when I tried running my application,
I am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to post a question and I was able to solved the problem.
I am posting a Q&A here just in case someone will encounter the same problem
I have.

Only copy the Parse-*.jar file to your /apps/libs folder, in  my case
this is Parse-1.9.1.jar. If you have accidentally copied the bolt-adnroid-1.2.0.jar to the /apps/libs folder, remove it as it will prevent your
application from building.

I read the quickstart of Parse again and it says to just copy the Parse-*.jar
to the libs folder.

I hope this will be useful to others as well.